# What is the difference between "1.0f" and "1.f"?

Tags: c++, floating-point, conventions

As a worshipper of John Carmack, I was reading Id Tech's publicly-available Coding Conventions document (at ftp://ftp.idsoftware.com/idstuff/doom3/source/CodeStyleConventions.doc if you're interested), and came across a convention I didn't entirely understand:

> Use precision specification for floating point values unless there is an explicit need for a double.
>
> `float f = 0.5f`
>
> Instead of
>
> `float f = 0.5;`
>
> And
>
> `float f = 1.0f;`
>
> Instead of
>
> `float f = 1.f;`

How are these different?

I can understand the difference between the two in the first example (the latter doing a double-to-float conversion under the hood), although I'd suspect it only needs a not-stupid compiler to catch and would produce the same bytecode, for no runtime difference.

But is there any case where adding trailing 0's to your floating point value declaration changes things?

Comment: It feels more like a typo in context, since both of the two have a precision specification. 1.0f is still more readable, though.

Comment: The author probably meant to suggest `float f = 1.0f;` instead of `float f = 1.0;`; the presence or absence of the `f` suffix is the point. (And it's usually better to use `double` rather than `float` anyway.)

Comment: A good compiler should warn if you initialize a `float` with `double` constant whose value changes when converted to `float`, but it should not, as a rule, produce the same code as if the constant had been suffixed with `f`. This is because there are some numerals that are different when first converted to `double` and then to `float` than when converted directly to `float`. It would be unusual for a programmer to use these intentionally, but it is a legitimate use of the language and should be compiled as stated.

Answer (score 12):

> But is there any case where adding trailing 0's to your floating point value declaration changes things?

The only "thing" that adding a zero would change is readability. The resultant code would be exactly the same, because compilers do not care, but the constant with a zero in place would be easier to read by the human readers.

Comment: Readability! So often overlooked.

Comment: Meaningful only to humans, yes.  There for readability, maybe not.  Most people dealing with numbers follow a convention where trailing zeros indicate number of significant digits.